# how to get application instance in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I can't find how to make something like ::getInstance() like in other php frameworks to get Application (singleton) instance in symfony2

I found only sfContext::getInstance() buy it doesn't work and looks like its method from symfony1

add more info.

I have some class - abstract class Post { }. I want to get some application config, environment variables inside this class. i don't want to put all this  stuff to constructor method, instead i want to call application instance and get all i want

Comment: You should read the documentation first ;) http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html

Comment: ok. what i should  do next ? )

Comment: Think about and try to solve your problem ;) we can't say when try and for what you need getInstance.

Comment: `i don't want to put all this stuff to constructor method` why not?

Comment: because almost all params will be the same for each object. they just located in global config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at web/app.php you will see that your application instance is just a global variable called kernel

```
    $kernel = $GLOBALS['kernel'];
    die(get_class($kernel));
```

However, the reason @san40 told you to read the documents is that you probably never actually need it for anything.  SF2 is very different than SF1.  So if you explained why your wanted the instance then someone might be able to suggest alternative approaches.

===================================

Looking at web/console shows that same principle for console commands except the instance is called application.

```
die(get_class($GLOBALS['application']))
```

However, using the application instance to pull environment variables and such is not recommended.  If nothing else, it makes your objects completely dependent in the instance.   Dependency injection is what you want.  Read through the stuff in the s2 documentation.

Comment: thanks. but your solution works only if i run script from browser, if use php app/console it didn't works. I add more explanation ...

Comment: Thanks a lot. i can use something like 
$GLOBALS['kernel']->getContainer()->getParameter('any_param'); 
or make shortcut for my own getInstance function.

Comment: You could but consider just injecting the container into your service.  Though even that is frowned on but it's better than grabbing it out of globals.  And if you are doing an SF2 type app then really should not need any getInstance stuff.  Turn your singletons into services.